JavaScript Riddle Game: Incorrect Input Validation Always Returns Correct, How to Fix?
This basic riddle game presents the player with a random riddle from an array of objects and prompts them to input their answer. but, there's an issue with input validation causing incorrect answers to be accepted as correct.
I tried checking for syntax errors, if there's any mistakes in my if statements and making sure if the input validation is correct but no luck. I'm new to javascript


$(document).ready(function() {
  let riddles = [{
      question: 'What word contains all of the twenty-six letters?',
      answer: 'alphabet'
    },
    {
      question: 'Which word in the dictionary is spelled incorrectly?',
      answer: 'incorrectly'
    },
    {
      question: 'What color can you eat?',
      answer: 'orange'
    },

    {
      question: 'What has a head, a tail, is brown, and has no legs?',
      answer: 'penny'
    },
    {
      question: 'I’m tall when I’m young, and I’m short when I’m old. What am I?',
      answer: 'candle'
    },
    {
      question: 'What can travel around the world while staying in a corner?',
      answer: 'stamp'
    },
    {
      question: 'What has keys but can’t open locks?',
      answer: 'piano'
    },
    {
      question: 'What has one eye but can’t see?',
      answer: 'needle'
    }

  ];

  $('.startBtn').on('click', function() {
    // Select and display a random riddle
    let selectedRiddle = riddles[Math.floor(Math.random() * riddles.length)];
    $('.theRiddle').text(selectedRiddle.question);
    $('.result').empty();
  });

  $('.submitBtn').on('click', function() {
    let playerGuess = $('.answer-section').val();

    if (playerGuess === '') {
      $('.result').text('Please guess or enter "quit" to exit.');
    } else {
      let selectedRiddle = $('.theRiddle').text();

      if (playerGuess.toLowerCase() === 'quit') {
        $('.result').text('Thanks for playing! Goodbye.');
        $('.theRiddle').empty();
      } else if (playerGuess.toLowerCase() !== selectedRiddle.answer) {
        $('.result').text('Incorrect answer. Try again.');
      } else(playerGuess.toLowerCase() === selectedRiddle.answer)
      $('.result').text('CORRECT! You win!\nThe answer is: ' + playerGuess);
      $('.theRiddle').empty();
    }

  });
});
.riddleSection {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.answer-section {
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-right: 170px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.answer-section input::placeholder {
  color: #999;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.submitBtn,
.startBtn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.startBtn:hover,
.submitBtn:hover {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

.theRiddle {
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.headingOne {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 9px;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.result {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
<!-- heading section -->
<h1 class="headingOne">Riddle Game</h1>


<!-- riddle appears here -->
<p class="theRiddle"></p>

<!-- answer section -->
<div class="riddleSection">
  <input class="answer-section" placeholder="Enter your answer">
  <button class="submitBtn">Submit</button>
  <button class="startBtn">Start Game</button>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Your code sets selectedRiddle to the text of the riddle element on the page. Then you compare the player guess to selectedRiddle.answer. How is it that you expect that selectedRiddle string to have an "answer" property? (It won't; selectedRiddle.answer will be undefined.)

Also that if sequence is malformed; the last else is followed by an expression in parentheses. I don't know what you want that to do, but it's not correct.

Put console.log statements everywhere and see what you see in the dev console.

so selectedRiddle doesnt point to the object in the array and selectedRiddle.answer doesnt point to the answers? im a bit confused

You're doing this for the win-check:
 else if (playerGuess.toLowerCase() !== selectedRiddle.answer) {

But right above it you call
let selectedRiddle = $('.theRiddle').text();

So selectedRiddle just hold the question text, retreived from the .theRiddle element. So it does not contain the object as you're expecting.


You can use riddles.find() to find the answer you need from the original array:
let selectedRiddle = riddles.find(r => r.question === $('.theRiddle').text());


I've inverted the if/else logic

If it matches, the answer is correct
else it's not correct no need for a !==




Demo showing the above points applied, the 'Incorrect answer' message is at the bottom of the page, so don't forget to scroll down after giving the wrong answer.


let riddles = [{question: 'What word contains all of the twenty-six letters?', answer: 'alphabet' }, {question: 'Which word in the dictionary is spelled incorrectly?', answer: 'incorrectly' }, {question: 'What color can you eat?', answer: 'orange' }, {question: 'What has a head, a tail, is brown, and has no legs?', answer: 'penny' }, {question: 'I’m tall when I’m young, and I’m short when I’m old. What am I?', answer: 'candle' }, {question: 'What can travel around the world while staying in a corner?', answer: 'stamp' }, {question: 'What has keys but can’t open locks?', answer: 'piano' }, {question: 'What has one eye but can’t see?', answer: 'needle' } ];

$('.startBtn').on('click', function() {
    // Select and display a random riddle
    let selectedRiddle = riddles[Math.floor(Math.random() * riddles.length)];
    $('.theRiddle').text(selectedRiddle.question);
    $('.result').empty(); 
});

$('.submitBtn').on('click', function() {
    let playerGuess = $('.answer-section').val();
    
    if (playerGuess === '') {
      $('.result').text('Please guess or enter "quit" to exit.');
    } else {
      let selectedRiddle = riddles.find(r => r.question === $('.theRiddle').text());
      if (playerGuess.toLowerCase() === 'quit') {
        $('.result').text('Thanks for playing! Goodbye.');
        $('.theRiddle').empty();
      } else if (playerGuess.toLowerCase() === selectedRiddle.answer) {
        $('.result').text('CORRECT! You win!\nThe answer is: ' + playerGuess);
        $('.theRiddle').empty();
      } else {
        $('.result').text('Incorrect answer. Try again.');
      }
    } 
});
.riddleSection {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.answer-section{
 
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-right: 170px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.answer-section input::placeholder {
  color: #999; 
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.submitBtn, .startBtn{
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.startBtn:hover, .submitBtn:hover{
  background-color: dimgray;
}
.theRiddle{
  margin-top: 80px;

  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.headingOne{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 9px;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.result{

  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;

}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Riddle Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="riddleStyles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- heading section -->
    <h1 class="headingOne">Riddle Game</h1>


    <!-- riddle appears here -->
    <p class="theRiddle"></p>

    <!-- answer section -->
    <div class="riddleSection">
      <input class="answer-section" placeholder="Enter your answer">
      <button class="submitBtn">Submit</button>
      <button class="startBtn">Start Game</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="riddleScript.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>




i was under the impression that the selectedRiddle.answer would find the answer in the array of objects?

Nope, please see my edit

im still a bit confused sir

About what part?

thank you . i will need to study more on the find function

That might help. You only have access to the question, so we're using find to search the riddles array for the object which has the question we got from $('.theRiddle').text(). find will return the object, so then you have access to .answer. Hope this makes it clear. Please upvote/accept any answers that might have helped to give you and the answerer some reputation ;)

Why did you un-accepted my answer @mather?

As 0stone0 said, let selectedRiddle = $('.theRiddle').text(); is just getting the text of that element so selectedRiddle.answer will always be undefined. You need to store the answer as data.
After this line:
let selectedRiddle = riddles[Math.floor(Math.random() * riddles.length)];
Add this:
jQuery(".theRiddle").data("answer", selectedRiddle.answer);
then you can access the answer like:
jQuery(".theRiddle").data("answer");
That way you won't have to filter/find anything
